# How to make a page can be swiped left and right in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic3

In ionic 3, how to make a div can be swiped left and right? The contents is a list of ion-card, I would like to make it be viewed by swiping left and right.

```
   <ion-item>
     <div *ngFor="let subtrip of trips" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': subtrip.borderColor}">
        <ion-card>
          <ion-item text-wrap>
            <p> subtrip.id </p>
            <ion-avatar item-start >
              <img src="assets/img/car.png" style="...">
            </ion-avatar>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-card>
     </div>
   </ion-item>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use ion-slides [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/slides/Slides/)

this way you can slid contents , and slide anything inside it